# Creating a static library + UI from existing source

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

Ladies and gents,

I'm having a brain-itching issue with something I deem rather simple.
The case is as follows:

We created a native iOS app, and we want to create some customised versions of the app using the same source and resources. The project is rather large though, so creating multiple targets and linking against almost a 100 files would be overkill in my opinion. So I figured that it would probably be the best idea to create these customised versions of this app using a statically linked library of the original source. So I created multiple types of statically linked libraries using the many solutions our fellow developers provide on the internet. I've come across [Jeff Verkoeyen's tutorial](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) and the [iOS Universal Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework), both providing me with an excellently built framework including my UIStoryboard files.

There's only one problem, after including the framework and finding the UIStoryboard files I've managed to get everything running. But after running the application the app instantly crashes notifying me that it couldn't find the custom classes I've used in the UIStoryboard to make the app work.

For instance, I've made subclasses for UIViewController (of which all my other ViewControllers inherit), so I could use my code more optimal. The actual subview (BaseViewController) is not to be found by the UIStoryboard. I'll have to note that the actual class files (.h and .m) are inside the framework I've created using any of the above methods.

So, what am I to do now. I really need a solution for either this problem or a hint to another solution that would be fitting for my current problem, which is; I want to create customised versions of apps using a single code base.

Thanks in advance!

- Bryan

Comment: Could you post what exactly your crash log shows.. So that we can say what you have to do in easy way. Anyway it's going to be simple like `include(import)` your framework header file in the `viewController` which you got crashed. So that I am asking you to post the crash log.

Comment: Everything is imported as it should. The problem is that the StoryBoard can't find the classes it inherits its view controllers from. Even though the classes are included and imported straight from the framework itself...

Comment: In the Interface Builder, did you changed the type of ViewController to your BaseViewController? When you are creating StoryBoard Files, or ViewControllers or visual interface, there is a combobox, in the menu on the right, that you should see UIViewController. Change it to BaseViewController.

Comment: Of course, how would it otherwise complain about the fact it can't find the correct class files?